# let $F(x)=\int^x_1 t^{\sqrt {t}}dt$ be defined for every $x\ge 0$, then..

Tags: calculus

a) $F(x)>0$ for every $x>0$.
b) $F(x)>F(e)$ for every $x>1$.
c) $x=e^{-2}$ is an inflection point. 
d) None of the answers are correct. 

Note: This was a question in my exam and I wrote it from my memory so if there's something that doesn't make sense it might be that I messed up. 
My Work was to take second derivative of $F$ and saw that $F''(e^{-2})\ne 0$, so I took out that option, and didn't know how to decide between (a) or (b), but I noticed that for (a) I might have to flip the integral, so I just went with (b), I would appreciate any explanation on how to really approach this question and not just with my intuition. (and know if I got it right too).

Comment: $F(1)=\int_1^1=0$

Comment: c) can be said to wrong because a number is not a point (:

Comment: @David P: This formulation is only an ellipsis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you apply the *First fundamental theorem* of integral calculus, you have
$$F'(x)=x^{\sqrt x},\enspace \text{hence }\quad F''(x)=x^{\sqrt x}\biggl(\frac{\ln x}{2\sqrt x}+\frac{\sqrt x}x\biggr)=x^{\sqrt x}\,\frac{\ln x+2}{2\sqrt x}$$
Therefore, $F''(x)=0$ for $x=\mathrm e^{-2}$, and it changes sign at that point, which means we have an inflection point.

Comment: rip, I got that same second derivative and still messed up with my calculations, how sad. I really appreciate the answer though :)

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation!

Comment: Oops, sorry. I did not re-check that claim.

Comment: It happens to all of us, from time to time…

Answer (score 2):

- ($a$) is wrong because $F(1) = 0$.
- ($b$) is wrong because $F'(x)=x^{\sqrt {x}} > 0$ so the function is increasing.
- ($c$) is wrong as you have checked.
- ($d$) therefore, is the correct option.

**Edit:** ($c$) option appears to be correct as @Bernard has shown. I was just convinced by the claim in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and rip to my final